# Flow Type: Return type of the function to be same as args of a callback?

Tags: javascript, flowtype, typing

I have the following function –

```
function wrapper(callback) {
  // operation
}
```

I need the return type of `wrapper` to be the same as the first(only) argument passed to `callback`. For eg.

```
wrapper(({paramA, paramB}) => {}) 
// returns { paramA: somveVal, paramB: someVal }
```

Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1):

```
function wrapper<T>(callback: T => mixed): T { ...}
```

Note that this signature is unimplementable unless you didn't actually want it to be generic.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand well, you need something like this:

For example declare `type CallBack`:

```
type CallBack = {|
  paramA: any,
  paramB: any,
 // Or use other type instead any.
|}
```

And `annotate` *function*:

```
const wrapper = (fn: (x: CallBack) => CallBack): CallBack => ({ paramA: 1, paramB: 2 });
```

Flow example:
[Flow Try](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgDCAhjDAELEDGA1gCq4EC8YA3gD6oCQOxATsQC2AQQBcYYgDssAGlRgwPfkPLips+QrDBgYAPJ8wAVwDOBOBgAWeQ9nxgAlpJMY8xACYTpAOlTsAvgDc6FRwzhhgCAI4+IYsABRQkuLxAB7iJGSUtAz4AJRgTAB8RKQU1PSMeRll2ZX2xWDxrGC8AiLiAIwyrcqCqmAATGD+ecFAA)